# Unable to install ruby 1.9.3 through Xcode 4.5.1 on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, xcode, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.5, ruby-1.9.3

I'm running Mac OS 10.8.2 and Xcode 4.5.1.  I installed the command line tools through Xcode which from what I've read is supposed to install ruby 1.9.3.  However, when I run `ruby -v` in terminal it still shows up as 1.9.2.  Is there something I'm missing here?  Thanks in advance

Comment: The command line tools still install 1.8.7. To install 1.9.x you will need a tool like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/). You can keep Xcode + the command line tools installed, install one of the ruby managers mentioned above, and download the ruby version you want then flag it as "global". `ruby -v` will then output the correct version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to install ruby-1.9.3 would be using rvm or rbenv. Also, in OS X, i would recommend homebrew for custom packages.

You can follow the instructions on http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: thanks, I had misunderstood and thought the command line tools install 1.9.3 for you